# Docker Wordpress - Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I created a simple WordPress app in Docker by following [this tutorial](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/run-docker-wordpress). After `docker-compose up -d`, I was treated with a simple setup. Once done, I am getting this error:

```
Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/update.php on line 209 Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/update.php on line 447 Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/update.php on line 728 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-includes/update.php:209) in /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 1416 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-includes/update.php:209) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6865 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-includes/update.php:209) in /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin-header.php on line 9 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-includes/update.php:209) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/option.php on line 1138 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-includes/update.php:209) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/option.php on line 1139
```

The `option.php` file looks something like this (starting `line 1137`):

```php
$secure = ( 'https' === parse_url( admin_url(), PHP_URL_SCHEME ) );
setcookie( 'wp-settings-' . $user_id, $settings, time() + YEAR_IN_SECONDS, SITECOOKIEPATH, '', $secure );
    setcookie( 'wp-settings-time-' . $user_id, time(), time() + YEAR_IN_SECONDS, SITECOOKIEPATH, '', $secure );
    $_COOKIE[ 'wp-settings-' . $user_id ] = $settings;
}
// ...
```

Here's the `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```yaml
version: '3'
# Defines which compose version to use
services:
  # Services line define which Docker images to run. In this case, it will be MySQL server and WordPress image.
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    # image: mysql:5.7 indicates the MySQL database container image from Docker Hub used in this installation.
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <root_password>
      MYSQL_DATABASE: <db>
      MYSQL_USER: <user>
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: <password>
    volumes:
      - ./db:/usr/lib/mysql:rw
      # Previous four lines define the main variables needed for the MySQL container to work: database, database username, database user password, and the MySQL root password.
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_USER: <user>
      PMA_PASSWORD: <password>
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    # Restart line controls the restart mode, meaning if the container stops running for any reason, it will restart the process immediately.
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
      # The previous line defines the port that the WordPress container will use. After successful installation, the full path will look like this: http://localhost:8000
    environment:
      # debug mode
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: <user>
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: <password>
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: <userdb>
    # Similar to MySQL image variables, the last four lines define the main variables needed for the WordPress container to work properly with the MySQL container.
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html:rw
volumes:
  mysql: {}
```

How do I solve this problem?

I found out about the problem after WordPress site failed to connect to the Internet. The error became visible once I started the debug mode with `WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1` based on some stackoverflow answer. This problem seems a bit weird to me since I have not made a single modification to the site.

The issue persists even after deleting all the files, containers and starting the `docker-compose` again.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Turns out, it was an issue with my institute's firewall. They have blocked the access to Wordpress, for some reason. It worked like a charm once I used my personal hotspot.